# php artisan migrate could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm learning front-end and my friend is learning back-end, he finished a project using Laravel and then I moved the project to my laptop so I can run it locally on my laptop and try the API he created on my Flutter app, I have no experience in PHP/Laravel but I searched online and did the following steps:

1. Donwloaded composer, PHP, MySQL, XAMPP.
2. Opened the project in cmd and wrote `composer update`.
3. I Ran Apache server and MySQL in XAMPP and they worked perfectly, so I entered phpMyAdmin and created a database with the same name in the `.env` file.
4. in the cmd I wrote `php artisan migrate` but I ran into this error:
   [image: error image]

I searched it online and found a lot of people with the same error but all of them fixed it by uncommenting the `pdo_mysql` extension in the `php.ini` file, but it didn't work for me and still facing the same problem.

I'm using Windows 11 if it matters.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of xampp or other similar apps like wamp in your PC? Did you restart the apache service?